# QML code and Animations not working as expected

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, qt-quick, qqmlcomponent

In my QML program I need to use `Animation`s to test for a problem. Please run the code below on your system. I don't know why when I use this `ParallelAnimation` the *ball* doesn't reflect when it hits the walls!

Here is *main.qml*:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 720
    height: 620

    Rectangle {
        id: table
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "gray"

        Rectangle {
            id: ball
            property double xincrement: Math.random() + 0.5 
            property double yincrement: Math.random() + 0.5
            width: 15
            height: width
            radius: width / 2
            color: "white"
            x: 300; y: 300
        }

        Racket {
            id: myRacket
            x: table.width - 50
            y: table.height/3
            color: "blue"
        }

        ParallelAnimation {
            id: anim
            NumberAnimation {
                target: ball
                properties: "x"
                to: timer.xMove
            }
            NumberAnimation {
                target: ball
                properties: "y"
                to: timer.yMove
            }
        }

        Timer {
            id: timer
            interval: 20; repeat: true; running: true
            property double xMove: ball.x + ball.xincrement
            property double yMove: ball.y + ball.yincrement

            onTriggered: {
                if(ball.x + ball.width >= table.width || ball.x <= 0)
                    ball.xincrement *= -1

                xMove += ball.xincrement
                yMove += ball.yincrement
                anim.restart()

                if(ball.y <= 0 || ball.y + ball.height >= table.height)
                    ball.yincrement *= -1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's also *Racket.qml*:

```
import QtQuick 2.9

Rectangle {
    id: root
    width: 15; height: 65

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: root
        anchors.margins: -root.height
        drag.target: root
        drag.axis: Drag.YAxis
        drag.minimumY: 0
        drag.maximumY: 600
    }
}
```

**EDIT1**:

I used this code without `Animation`s and it works well! (The dropped parts are the same)

```
...
Rectangle {
            id: ball
            property double xincrement: Math.random() + 0.5
            property double yincrement: Math.random() + 0.5
            width: 15
            height: width
            radius: width / 2
            color: "white"
            x: 300; y: 300
        }
...

Timer {
            id: timer
            interval: 20; repeat: true; running: true

            onTriggered: {
                if(ball.x + ball.width >= table.width || ball.x <= 0)
                    ball.xincrement *= -1

                ball.x += ball.xincrement * 2.0
                ball.y += ball.yincrement * 2.0

                if(ball.y <= 0 || ball.y + ball.height >= table.height)
                    ball.yincrement *= -1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is something like this: I have a problem with Animation, your solution to eliminate Animation, that is the solution to any problem, I understand that the solution you were looking for is to solve your problem even with Animation, but it seems that it is not.

Comment: Why did you down-voted the question and also deleted your answer!? I'm a new learner and may have many questions to learn things properly.

Comment: I did not say the down-vote you mention, I eliminated my question as I thought that you already have your own solution.

Comment: Sorry but I do not have a solution and as I stated in my question *"I need to use `Animation`s to test for a problem*". So using `Animation`s a new solution is needed. And also I may have questions and the question I asked was about the different behavior of the program with and without `Animations`.

Comment: Have you tried my solution?

Comment: Your question should be specific, if you have other questions create other posts, SO works.

Comment: Yes, thanks. It works but why those many else-if are not needed in the version without Animations (sections EDIT1) because hitting the walls is independent of the way the ball moves.

Comment: the problem with the use of the Timer that you will have in the future is that you will overload your application if you do not have an adequate handling, if you use Animation this will update the position in an appropriate way taking the refresh time from the window.

Comment: A code should be clear, if you could not have problems like the one you had, the error I had is to have a "compact" code, I only separated it without adding more calculation, that is, at the computer level it had the same cost, it is preferred to use addition or subtraction, or inversion of signs that multiplication by -1

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `PropertyAnimation` has [a default duration of 250 ms](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-propertyanimation.html#duration-prop).

Adding

```
duration: 0
```

to both of your `NumberAnimation` will correct the problem and is equivalent to your second solution without animations.

However you can reproduce the exact same behavior with pure animation without any `Timer`:

```
ParallelAnimation {
    id: anim

    property double xMove: ball.x + ball.xincrement
    property double yMove: ball.y + ball.yincrement

    NumberAnimation {
        target: ball
        properties: "x"
        to: anim.xMove
        duration: 20
    }

    NumberAnimation {
        target: ball
        properties: "y"
        to: anim.yMove
        duration: 20
    }

    onStopped: {
        updatePosition()
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        updatePosition()
    }

    function updatePosition() {
        if(ball.x + ball.width >= table.width || ball.x <= 0)
            ball.xincrement *= -1

        if(ball.y <= 0 || ball.y + ball.height >= table.height)
            ball.yincrement *= -1

        anim.xMove += ball.xincrement
        anim.yMove += ball.yincrement
        anim.restart()
    }
}
```